# WSO2EI - Version 6.4.0 - How to set User-Agent header to anything other than Axis2

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, user-agent, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

**Setup**

Client -> WSO2EI -> Backend Server

The backend Server forces my WSO2EI to be of some specific User-Agent (Say 'I_M_ABC').

**Issue**
The solution is to set the user agent before using the call mediator to call the back end server. However, the WSO2EI forces the User-Agent always to be "Axis2".

**Code Snippets**

```
<property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" value="POST"/>

<header name="Action" value="''"/>

<header name="To" expression="fn:concat($ctx:uri.var.server.url, $ctx:uri.var.server.path)"/>

<property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>

<property name="PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING" value="true"/> 

<property name="preserveProcessedHeaders" value="true" scope="default"/>

<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/> -

<property name="UsesAgent" scope="default" type="STRING" value="I_AM_ABC"/>

<header expression="get-property('UsesAgent')"  name="User-Agent" scope="transport"/>

<header expression="get-property('messageType')"  name="Content-Type" scope="transport"/>
```

**LOG MESSAGE**
Relevant log entries

```
POST /path_to_resource HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]
cache-control: no-cache[\r][\n]
User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]
Host: www.myhostcom[\r][\n]
```

**What have I done**

1. changed passthru-http.properties for user-agent [did not work]
2. changed axis.xml commented out userAgent [did not work]

I also tried to preserve the user agent and from the client call, passed user agent. However, that also changed to Axis2.

3. changed nhttp.properties file (http.user.agent.preserve=true) - Did not work.
4. changed passthru-http.properties file (http.user.agent.preserve=true) - Did not work.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using call mediator with blocking mode or non-blocking mode?